# How to place the drop-down list and textInput horizontally

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a shiny app. I am facing an issue in placing the elements horizontally.

The **RCode** used is as follows:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         selectizeInput("proj1", NULL,
                        choices = Dummy$Project_1, width = "300px",
                        options = list(
                          placeholder = "Additional Projects",
                          onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                        )
         )),
  column(3, textAreaInput("col11","", width = "200px", height = "43px")),
  column(3, textAreaInput("col12","", width = "200px", height = "43px")),
  column(3, textAreaInput("col13","", width = "200px", height = "43px"))
)
)
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your selectize Input instead of NULL, if you give some header, then it will work fine. Below is the code:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           selectizeInput("proj1", "Choose value",
                          choices = c("A","B"), width = "300px",
                          options = list(
                            placeholder = "Additional Projects",
                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                          )
           )),
    column(3, textAreaInput("col11","", width = "200px", height = "43px")),
    column(3, textAreaInput("col12","", width = "200px", height = "43px")),
    column(3, textAreaInput("col13","", width = "200px", height = "43px"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Or just add `""` instead of `"Choose value"`